# android: How to apply pinch zoom and pan to 2D GLSurfaceView

Tags: 2d, android, opengl-es2

I want to apply pinch zoom and panning effect on GLSurfaceView. It is Image editor, so It would not be 3D object. I tried to implement using these following links:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/EVNRDNInVRU

Want to apply pinch and zoom to GLSurfaceView(3d Object)
http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/

These all are links for 3D object rendering. I can not use ImageView as I need to work out with OpenGL so, had to implement it on GLSurfaceView.

Suggest me or any reference links are there for such implementation.
**I need it for 2D only.

I am able to do both now, but where I am getting problem is to set the pivot point while panning can any one help me to set the translation respective to pivot point?

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(mScaleMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.scaleM(mScaleMatrix, 0, scaleX, scaleY, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mScaleMatrix, 0);
Matrix.setIdentityM(mTranslateMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.translateM(mTranslateMatrix, 0, deltaX, deltaY, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0,
                    mTranslateMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
```

Comment: Have you tried the standard Android way of implementing a gesture listener with a motiondetector on your activity?

Comment: Yes I have implemented that but how to scale GLSurfaceView? do you have any reference link or code?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to scale your GLSurfaceView; instead you should adjust your projection matrix in order to achieve "zooming".

You are most likely using an orthographic projection for your 2D view, so have a look at [this thread](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/132061-help-with-orthographic-zoom) for a discussion on how to achieve zooming using `glOrtho()`.

Comment: Thanks a ton, @free3dom ! but I implemented ortho at Matrix level and its working fine and got success on pinch zoom but confused on panning it, It is possible by using Matrix.translateM() too. But dont know what the exactly translate values to be passed, can u help me on this? thanks in advance

Comment: For panning it would probably be easiest to do that with the MODEL VIEW matrix, instead of the projection matrix. So instead of using an identity matrix as the starting point you use your "panned" coordinates as a TRANSLATION matrix, which all your "models" would then be transformed by - think of it as a global transform for all the objects in your world, i.e. their world coordinates transformed by your "pan coordinates".

Comment: hey free3dom can you tell me how could i set the pivot point while scaling, cos i need to translate with pivot point in scaling. Currently, when i scale matrix it does center point scaling because in translation matrix the pivot point always stays at center point, how can set pivot in translation matrix??

Comment: To set the pivot point you FIRST translate (to change the current position to your desired pivot point), then perform scaling. This should be done in model (local) space of the object you are scaling.

Comment: i m scaling the view matrix and then applying translation to projection matrix, it is working fine in this matter but setting pivot is not possible. Do you want to say i should apply translation to view matrix if i m doing scaling only. can both translation work this way?

Comment: Sure, as long as you realize that doing so will affect the placement of the object since you are changing it's "origin"; i.e. it's position in world space will change accordingly. In other words you might still need to do translation to world space, but it would then need to be offset by the model space offset you used.

Comment: can you explain by considering the code above? I mean if i have focus point focusX,focusY while scrolling then how to mainpulate it?

Comment: In the code above, do the translation for pivot FIRST (before the scaling), then concatenate it with the scaling matrix and use the result as the model transform matrix. Then do the rest (view/projection) as usual.

Comment: As an alternative for local space scaling, you could also apply the scaling factor to the vertices of the object directly (using whatever pivot point you desire) while placing them in a vertex buffer.